# Panes/Widget interaction

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, dashboard, freeboard

Good morning,

I am about to build a dashboard and I am evaluation the Freeboard product that from a first look really amaze me!

I have a couple of questions to which I could not find answers in the docs:

Is it foreseen any kind of cross-panes/widgets communication? e.g. in case i need to refresh a pane if the user interact with another. I found the freeboard.on() method but from the events' catalog I only see two events, relative to the Freeboard's instance. I couldn't find freeboard.trigger() or similar function to trigger custom event.
Is it AMD supported (RequireJS)?
Thank you very much for your time and your support.

Daniele

[Git issue track](https://github.com/Freeboard/freeboard/issues/138)

Answer (score 0):

Cross widgets/panes communication is not available "out of the box" in freeboard.

There is a way to see the most current data for all datasources within any of the widgets by using the .JS Editor when connecting a widget to a datasource.

As per the help message in the editor: you can assume this .JS Editor is enclosed in a function of the form function(datasources) where datasources is a collection of objects (keyed by name) corresponding to the most current data for each datasource.

I hope this helps.